# Render two or more partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, render, partial-views

I have an Ajax.Actionlink that fires to a method that is placed inside my controller which returns a list of users and renders a partial view.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult UsersAddresses()
{
     ...
     ...
     return PartialView("AddressesList",users);
}
```

Is there any way how I can render two or more partial views at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to concatenate partial views together, make a partial view (we'll just call it *Parent*), then within that view call Html.RenderPartial() as many times as you need.  Then your controller can just return a View / PartialView for *Parent*, supplying the proper aggregate view data.

Comment: Thanks Levi, but I'm trying to render Partial Views that are on different scopes. For example, let's supposse that we would write our answers of stackoverflow on a popup (partial view) and there would be a counter on the back of the page being updated with the number of answers.

Comment: So the particular scenario is that you're doing this from an AJAX call and want to update multiple DIVs?  Currently there's no facility for pulling this off.  But if you include a dummy DIV as part of the response, you can probably check for this as part of the hookup event, then just move the contents of that DIV elsewhere.